# GhostDoc public const documentation

Tags: ghostdoc

When using ghostdoc on single line vars defs like

```
public const string DbCatName = "test";
```

ghostdoc adds a default header like :

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
```

but what I like to have is

```
/// <summary></summary>
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is GhostDoc Pro which has "XML Comment templates (T4) Total control over your XML documentation content and style"

From http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't get GhostDoc to do that for you - I believe the format it uses is pretty much fixed. [**edit:** It appears it may now be possible in GhostDoc Pro]

My addin, [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) will do exactly what you want though - it has a lot of preferences to control almost every aspect of how comments are formatted, indented and word wrapped.